# What is the keystroke to exit the file diff view in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am playing around with sublimerge. I got into the file diff view, having 2 panes. I don't know how to go back to the normal view.

Answer (score 16):

Clicking in the diff pane and pressing "esc" worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the source code and couldn't even find this trick. Real annoying feature

Answer (score 2):

You can open a new window with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
It should open in one-pane view.
If you not see the menu bar you can access the menu via the `command palette` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and type in `menu`, as is explained in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881586).
Save your workspace, in the Project menu.

Answer (score 0):

well I didn't find the keystroke yet, but you can at least hit the close buttons on the files in the side bar, and it does take you out of diff view mode

Comment: That closes the file in the edit view, but the diff pane remains open

Answer (score -2):

On a Mac, Cmd-Q seems to do it.