# Sublime only opens in Sublimerge view

Tags: view, merge, diff, sublimetext3, restore

I have the plugin `Sublimerge` installed in `Sublime Text 3`. In order to compare two files `Sublimerge` opens a new window (but without any menu). That is fine since the original `Sublime` window is still there.

Unfortunately the diff-window was the last one I closed and when I restart `Sublime` it opens the diff-view without menu.

Question is: How can I restore the default `Sublime` view?

To make my problem visible, this is what it looks like now:

[image]

Edit: Sublime is running on Linux Mint and is set to a German keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the `sidebar`, you press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to toggle it on/off.

To close the sublimerge diff window, just press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

edit after reading your comment/image:

To go back to a single pane view, press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Ultimately, you can access the FileDiffs menu via the `command palette` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and type in `menu`.

Comment: Added an image to make it clear. Sadly none of the short cuts worked. But I appreciate your effort :)

Comment: Forgot to tell that I am using Linux Mint (on a German keyboard) and some keys don't work the same way as on Windows. What I found was Ctrl+Shift+P and then type "menu" to toggle it. If you could add this to your answer I would be pleased to accept it since you were heading in the right direction by toggling back elements.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and selecting last project solved it.